# Cannot migrate in Laravel using 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have my app locally but i configured my .env and database.php in config\ to connect to a database hosted remotely in 000webhost but i get message whenever i perform  `php artisan migrate`

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

or do i need to host my app online in order for it to  work?  Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using 000webhost's free plan, which does not support remote MySQL connections. Their [paid accounts do](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-my-computer-27):

> ### How can I connect to MySQL from my computer?
>
> Remote MySQL connections are disabled for security and server performance reasons.
>
> However remote MySQL connections will be enabled if you upgrade your account

Comment: ah yes. im using free plan. Any recommendation for free remote MySQL Connections? just for learning Laravel.

Comment: @BlondePainter, sorry, [resource recommendations are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But if you search around you can probably find something. Or you could install it on your local machine (MySQL is free). Or you could use Laravel's [official development environment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead)…